# What is the correct syntax to create trigger to prevent from drop table

Tags: sql, triggers, teradata

I am looking for the correct syntax to create a trigger via TERADATA, to prevent from dropping the table and execute a rollback instead (for example).
For anyone answering:

1. trigger name = never_drop
2. schema name = comp
3. table name = maagar
4. I wish it to print a message to the log

thanks

Comment: There are no DDL triggers in Teradata. Simply revoke the DROP TABLE right

Comment: I asked because I saw the syntax in SQLSERVER. It seems there is no option in TERADATA.